# FInd expected value of X, which is the number of chosen items

Tags: probability

Can you help me to solve this probability problem?

There are `m` items in the row (line? Don't know how to say it more correctly in English). Randomly selected `k` items (k < m). Random variable `X` equals to the number of items `i` that `i` object is selected, and all its (`i`) neighbors are not selected. Find `EX`.

So, I know different determinations of expected value, but what to do with it i don't know.

Thank you!

Comment: You mean that $X$ count the isolated selected elements (those that have not a neighbour selected)?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for inaccuracy in description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the leftmost or rightmost point, the probability of being isolated (or the expected value of the number of isolated points at its position) is the probability that it is selected and that its neighbor is not: $\frac{k}{m}\frac{m-k}{m-1}$. For an interior point, the probability of being isolated (or the expected value of the number of isolated points at its position) is $\frac{m-k}{m}\frac{k}{m-1}\frac{m-k-1}{m-2}$.

By linearity of expectation, the expected value of the number of isolated points anywhere is the sum of the isolation probability over all points, which is
$$2\frac{k}{m}\frac{m-k}{m-1}+(m-2)\frac{m-k}{m}\frac{k}{m-1}\frac{m-k-1}{m-2}\\
=\frac{k (k-m-1) (k-m)}{(m-1) m}.$$

Added in response to Porfiriy’s comment:

The reason an endpoint is isolated with probability $\frac{k}{m}\frac{m-k}{m-1}$ is as follows: Let $A$ be the event that the endpoint is selected and $B$ be the event that its neighbor is not selected. The probability that the endpoint is isolated is $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B\mid A)$. $P(A)=\frac{k}{m}$, and $P(B\mid A)$ is the probability that the neighbor is selected given that the endpoint is selected. If the endpoint is selected, any other point is selected with probability $\frac{k-1}{m-1}$, because other than the selected endpoint, there are $m-1$ points, $k-1$ of which are selected.

The other probability used, that an interior point is isolated, is calculated in a similar way. Let $A$ be the event that the interior point’s left neighbor is not selected, $B$ that the point itself is selected, and $C$ that its right neighbor is not selected. The probability of isolation is then $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)P(B\mid A)P(C\mid A\cap B)$ The left neighbor is not selected with probability $\frac{m-k}{m}$, because $m-k$ of the $m$ points are not selected. Given that it is not selected, the interior point itself is selected with probability $\frac{k}{m-1}$, because $k$ of the $m-1$ points other than the left neighbor are selected. Given that of the left neighbor and the interior point itself, one is selected, there are $k-1$ remaining points to be selected of the $m-2$ other points, leaving $m-2-(k-1)=m-k-1$ to be unselected, so the probability that one of these, the right neighbor, is unselected is $\frac{m-k-1}{m-2}$.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Could you explain please how did you get probabilities?

Comment: I updated my answer. (The explanation is longer than the answer was, but it’s still straightforward.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The key for this kind of problems is linearity of expectation. Let $Z_i$ be a random variable taking value $1$ if index $i$ corresponds to  isolated selected element, $0$ otherwise. The variables $Z_i$, $Z_{i+1}$ are not independent, but fortunately that does not matter, because to compute $E(X)$ we only need the expectations of each $Z_i$.